# How to use material components on index.html in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

Hi guys I've been trying to edit the codes here

https://stackblitz.com/angular/embgyqdqnjr?file=polyfills.ts

is it possible to use materials component on index.html example a button?

Comment: Yes it is possible - please be more specific about what you have tried, where you have got stuck etc, providing a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Found out that it is not possible, materials can only be added into components